# Getting ArcMap ERROR 010560

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

[image: These are the tools I ues.]I am using ArcMap 10.8.1.

I was using Extract Value To Points and it always failed ending up with:

> ERROR 010560: cannot create table or feature

as shown in the picture.

What may cause the problem?

Comment: It sounds like your output path doesn't exist, you don't have write access or you haven't set arcpy.env.overwriteOutput to True and the feature class already exists. Try a different tool like arcpy.CopyFeatures_management https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm to the same intended output and see if you can create it and if not perhaps you will get a more descriptive error message. This error message also happens with Excel or CSV input because field names don't need to be conforming and unique in the source table.

Comment: What happens if you copy your TIF file to be called something like C:\temp\test.tif and write your output to C:\temp\test.shp?

Comment: Your point layer is an event layer from Excel? try saving it as a feature class and use this as input